# Does order matter when it comes to AC power?

Tags: power, ac, dc, ac-dc

Is there anything about electricity or the electrical design of AC power strips that dictates *in what order* the devices should be plugged in?

When I say, "in what order", I am referring to the physical positioning, not the temporal order of *when* they are plugged in.

For example, let's say the user wants to plug in a toaster oven, FM radio, LCD TV, "smart" battery charger, cellphone, tablet, laptop computer, USB hub, and desktop computer into the same AC power strip.  Some of these items are AC-powered and some require AC-DC converters.

Assume that there is sufficient amperage from the mains to power all those devices and that the wiring is all less than 20 years old.

I'm thinking about EMF interference, power degradation, or sine wave distortion, but am open to all reasons why order may (or may not) be important.

Comment: I think the power strip is wired in parallel so I can't see how it would make any difference. Maybe someone else knows the subtleties...

Answer (score 3):

As Roger correctly notes - the outputs are all in parallel across the mains AC so, electrically, order is unimportant.

There could be some extremely small 2nd order effects due to heavy current flows from some devices allowing some form of subtle interactions depending on position but these would be immensely unlikely and a quick think suggests that it would be hard to make up a convincing example. (Unconvincing examples area easier. )

The most likely possible real world interaction may be from placing a power device nearer to or further from a noise sensitive device. eh a noisy smps power plug adaptor may induce noise into an nearby radio - but this is less likely f the radio if connected by cord and plug.